# Date parsing error by selecting different language selection on android device

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio-2.2

When I run my app, language selected is English and my app is working fine on android phone. Now when I change my phone language to Italia, then my app crashes. And it is date parsing error. App is crashing while parsing the date. Below is error code and also the crash logs.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        try {
            **parsedDate = sdf.parse(date.toString());** //app crashes on this line
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Error**

```
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: **Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 06 19:11:02 GMT+05:30 2017" (at offset 0)**
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at com.yapsody.yapstats.Activities.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:169)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-06 19:11:02.415 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-06 19:11:02.416 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
01-06 19:11:02.416 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-06 19:11:02.416 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-06 19:11:02.416 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-06 19:11:02.416 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-06 19:11:03.385 758-758/com.yapsody.yapstats E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.yapsody.yapstats, PID: 758
                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexo, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yapsody.yapstats/com.yapsody.yapstats.Activities.EventsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1197)
                                                                      at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:527)
                                                                      at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:829)
                                                                      at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
                                                                      at com.yapsody.yapstats.Activities.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:175)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: The value `"Fri Jan 06 19:11:02 GMT+05:30 2017"` is correct, what are Android version and device model?

Comment: I suspect the issue is in month names. Full month and weekday names are different from english in italian, so perfectly parsable date string appears to contain unknown tokens in another language

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can not comment in others posts.

I think the main problem is the NullPointerException at com.yapsody.yapstats.Activities.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:175)

Can you edit your question and show us that code?

Comment: NullPointerException is because of date parsing only. Refer below error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference`